# Naming conventions for permissions

Tags: coding-standards

Looking through the Drupal coding conventions on [Coding standards / Naming Conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/coding-standards#naming), I have seen module, variable, function, and many other areas but not for permission names.

Is there any convention to avoid creating permission names that might interfere with others?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no official recommendations.

Given that all permissions share the same namespace it's a good idea to avoid generic names. You can include the name of the module that defines the permissions to minimize collision risk.

Comment: Is this still the case for Drupal 8?

Comment: Drupal 8 changes how you declare permissions. Now they are declared in a yml file, with am id, title and desc. I suspect there's no collision problem because there are declared in different yml files, but I can't confirm this.

Comment: Looks like this is still the case. Even though we are putting them in yml files you still check for the permission string without any namespace. So there is still the chance for conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The Drupal coding standards do not say how permissions should be named, especially to avoid collisions between permissions defined from different projects.

The permission names used by Drupal core follow the schema `<verb> <object>`, as *administer users*, *view user email addresses*, *administer nodes*, and *administer content types*.
Usually, `<object>` is derived from the module name, and that avoids conflicts, but that is not always true.